# Set binding code behind for the DataTemplate does not work in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, datatemplate

I have to bind dynamic the Text property for the TextBlock in the WPF application in the runtime.
Here is the code:

In xaml file

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Double_View_Template">
    <TextBlock
        x:Name="txtDoubleViewTemplate" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        />
</DataTemplate>
```

In C#

```
DataTemplate data = FindResource("Double_View_Template") as DataTemplate;
TextBlock ui = data.LoadContent() as TextBlock;
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Mass");
BindingOperations.SetBinding(ui, TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);

DataGridTemplateColumn column = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
column.CellTemplate = data;
instrumentDataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
```

When run the application I see only blank lines, and the values are not shown in the Datagrid. The ItemsSource and the DataContext is correctly set.
If I set

```
 Text="{Binding Path=Mass}"
```

in the xaml the data is displayed.

Any idea why in the runtime the binding is not set?

Comment: LoadContent creates a new TextBlock instance. So you are setting the Binding on a TextBlock that is not part of your application's visual tree. `data.FindName("txtDoubleViewTemplate", column);` might work.

Comment: Thanks Clemens, I tried but got this error Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTemplateColumn' to 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement'